# atributo enum combox

Tags: java, java-swing, enum

Tengo un atributo de tipo enum {V,M} y tengo que asignarle el valor mediante un combox desde una aplicación swing que estoy haciendo desde otra clase de otro paquete, el caso es que no sé como invocar el atributo desde su clase a la de la aplicación dentro del método del evento.

¿Podríais indicarme algún ejemplo?

Comment: Ese atributo que necesitas asignar a través de la interfaz, a qué clase pertenece. Sé un poco más específico e indica las relaciones entre las clases implicadas.

Answer (score 0):

Seguramente con este ejemplo te puedas orientar mejor.
Clase enum

```
public enum DiasSemanas {
 LUNES, MARTES, MIERCOLES, JUEVES, VIERNES, SABADO, DOMINGO;
}
```

Luego una clase que la implemente

```
public class Enumeraciones {


public Enumeraciones() {
    super();

}

public void actividadesDiarias(DiasSemanas ds) {
    switch(ds) {
    case LUNES:
        System.out.println("Es el primer dia de la semana");
        break;
    case MARTES:
        System.out.println("Es el segundo dia de la semana");
        break;
    case MIERCOLES:
        System.out.println("Es el tercer dia de la semana");
        break;
    case JUEVES:
        System.out.println("Es el cuarto dia de la semana");
        break;
    case VIERNES:
        System.out.println("Es el quinto dia de la semana");
        break;
    case SABADO:
        System.out.println("Es el sexto dia de la semana");
        break;
    case DOMINGO:
        System.out.println("Es el septimo dia de la semana");
        break;
    default:
        System.out.println("Opcion no valida...!!!");
        break;


    }

}
```

y finalmente la ejecuto desde una clase main

```
public class Ejemplos {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Enumeraciones enumeraciones = new Enumeraciones();
    enumeraciones.actividadesDiarias(DiasSemanas.LUNES);
    enumeraciones.actividadesDiarias(DiasSemanas.MIERCOLES);

    String[] lista = { "Lunes", "Martes", "Miercoles", "Jueves", "Viernes","Sabado", "Domingo" };


    JComboBox combo = new JComboBox(lista);
    combo.setSelectedIndex(0); // establecemos el primer valor por defecto
    combo.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            System.out.println("Evento");

            if (combo.getSelectedIndex() == 5) {
                enumeraciones.actividadesDiarias(DiasSemanas.SABADO);   
            }



        }
    });


    JFrame ventana = new JFrame();
    ventana.getContentPane().setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    ventana.getContentPane().add(combo);
    ventana.pack();
    ventana.setVisible(true);
    ventana.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

}

}
```

Aqui solo lo que te queda es en esta ultima clase implementar el JComboBox

Answer (score 0):

Muchas gracias!

Creo que lo tengo igual, pero me sigue dando un error. Te lo detallo un poco resumido:

Por un lado tengo la clase con el atributo enum:

```
public class Medicos{

private enum Respuesta {S,N};

public void eleccionResp(Respuesta r){
    switch(r) {
        case S:
            r = Respuesta.S;
            break;
        case N:
            r = Respuesta.N;
            break;
    }

}
```

Por otro lado tengo la clase con la aplicación y un método con el evento:

```
private void jCB1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {

  Medicos m5 = new Medicos();
    int i = jCB1.getSelectedIndex();
    if(i == 0){
        m5.eleccionResp(r.S));// Aquí me da error (No puede encontrar la variable r)
    }else{}
 }
```

Se me escapa algo con la variable que no consigo averiguar...